# Repeats same entry.getValue().getName() for all the keys

Tags: java

i am new to this data structure. i have not been able to get the entered value for the key from a HashMap.

```
public class Patient {

    public String name,insurance;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }


    public void setInsurance(String insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance;
    }
```

I have a class administrator with HashMap that takes string as key and Object Patient as value. Enter values of name and insurance and put it in the HashMap.

```
public class Administrator{

    public Administrator() {
        }

HashMap <String,Patient> hashMap = new HashMap <String,Patient>();
static Patient patient = new Patient();
public  void PatientInfo(){

     String patientName = 'User input'
     String insurance = 'User input'
     patient.setName(patientName);
     patient.setInsurance(insurance);
     hashMap.put(patient.getName(),patient);
     }
}
```

(i enter value jay,aetna and rod,Metroplus)

Another class called PatientList that will list out the list of name and insurance entered.

```
public class PatientList{
     public PatientList(){}
public static table(Map<String,Patient>map){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Patient>entry : map.entrySet()){
         System.Out.println(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getInsurance());
         ///It prints jay aetna,rod aetna
          ///It prints same value for both different key.
{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sotirios Delimanolis,
Thank you for you help, using a fresh instance worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. On a side note, try to use `static` as little as possible.